Spring boot 3.3.3 spring-boot-maven-plugin- never executes
My spring application keeps generating the jar using maven-jar-plugin rather than using spring-boot-maven-plugin. Also I am upgrading Spring Boot 2.7.14 to 3.3.3.
I have this plugin in my pom.xml:
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>boot-repackage</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>boot-build-info</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-info</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalProperties>
                                    <java.source>java.version</java.source>
                                    <java.target>java.version</java.target>
                                </additionalProperties>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>...myApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

Also the jar file doesn't have boot-inf, only contains my application classes and no dependencies.
MANIFEST.MF inside the jar:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.4.2
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Implementation-Title: myApplication
Implementation-Version: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

My application runs without any issue in my local but when I try to deploy it to test environment the deployment fails with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication .
Initially I also had maven-jar-plugin in my pom.xml:
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>..myApplication</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

maven-jar-plugin was actually adding the mainClass in the MANIFEST.MF but then I thought spring-boot-maven-plugin wasn't executing properly because of it so I removed maven-jar-plugin, but even after removing maven-jar-plugin the MANIFEST.MF contains "Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.4.2". So I am thinking jar isn't properly generating with boot-inf/lib and the other folders because of maven-jar-plugin. I am not sure how maven-jar-plugin is in the project even though I removed it.

Looks like I added spring-boot-maven-plugin under:
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins> 

     spring-boot-maven-plugin

   <plugins>
</pluginManagement>

when it's suppose to be under plugins. Now my jar is generating correctly just not sure why MANIFEST.MF still has "Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.4.2".
